# How to link file in subdirectory to another subdirectory in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, command-line

My current directory contains two directories `test1` and `test2`.
`file1` is present in `test1`.

How can I create symbolic link in folder `test2/lin` for `file1`?

After the link operation Link file in `test2/lin` should point to `test1/file1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symlink resolution by the system is relative to the target (unless the link is absolute of course).

So it has to be considered as if you went into the final directory. In this case that would be (with explicit naming of the target):

```
cd test2/lin
ln -s ../../test1/file1 file1
```

The source doesn't change, that's the useful "content" of the symlink. So if you don't change directory, instead:

```
ln -s ../../test1/file1 test2/lin/file1
```

Comment: yes, no autocompletion by bash in this case, hence the mistakes often caused because of the availability of autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

From within your current directory it would be `ln -s test1/file1 test2/lin`.

You can also use a absolute path.
If the dir with `test1` and `test2` would be `/absolute/path/to/my2subdirs` then the command would become `ln -s /absolute/path/to/my2subdirs/test1/file1 /absolute/path/to/my2subdirs/test2/lin` and you could run it from outside of this directory

Comment: test2/lin is directory

Comment: `ln -s test1/file1 test2/lin` gives me error when I open (i.e This link cannot be used because its target "test1/File1/" doesn't exist.